# PHP string concat doesn't trigger

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I've got the following bit of code to check if a form with multiple fields are correctly filled. The problem is, is that it doesn't concat the strings properly.

Below is some code of the code:

```
if(strlen($name) < 2 || strlen($email) < 6 || strlen($subject) < 5 || strlen($message) < 15){
                $alert = "There are some problems: \n";

                if(strlen($name) < 2){
                    $alert . "Name is too short \n";
                }

                if(strlen($email) < 6){ 
                    $alert . "email is too short \n";
                }

                if(strlen($subject) < 5){
                    $alert . "The subject is too short \n";
                }

                if(strlen($message) < 15){ 
                    $alert . "Your message is too short \n";
                }

                $alert . "Please fill in te fields correctly";

                echo $alert;
                ?>
                <script>
                alert("<?= $alert ?>");
                </script>
                <?php
            }
            else { ... } ?>
```

If i place an echo inside each if statement it shows that it triggers, but in the end all that get's alerted and printed by the echo is "There are some problems:" 
Why doesn't the alert string gets properly concatinated? I tried removing the \n in each sentence but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing `$alert .= "something"`, not just `$alert . "something"`.

Comment: :O i've used string concat before with just . and it worked. Weird, but this one does the job - easy kuddo's for you hehe

Comment: Yes, `.` is the concatenation operator, but what your code was doing was concatenating the error message to the "There are some problems" text, and then doing nothing with the result. `.=` is kind of like `+=` in that `$a .= $b` is shorthand for `$a = $a.$b`.

Comment: This way you concat strigns, but do not assign the result to $alert. $alert .= 'something' is equal to $alert = $alert + 'something'

Comment: Yeah i understand it, i thought of . doing the .= actually. As you see.. every day you learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot concatenate variables like that, use `.=`

`.` will concatenate its right and left arguments. `.=` will append the argument on the right side to the argument on the left side.

```
if(strlen($name) < 2 || strlen($email) < 6 || strlen($subject) < 5 || strlen($message) < 15){
            $alert = "There are some problems: \n";

            if(strlen($name) < 2){
                $alert .= "Name is too short \n";
            }

            if(strlen($email) < 6){ 
                $alert .= "email is too short \n";
            }

            if(strlen($subject) < 5){
                $alert .= "The subject is too short \n";
            }

            if(strlen($message) < 15){ 
                $alert .= "Your message is too short \n";
            }

            $alert .= "Please fill in te fields correctly";

            echo $alert;
            ?>
            <script>
            alert("<?= $alert ?>");
            </script>
            <?php
        }
        else { ... } ?>
```